# Why are there so many questions on inflation lately?

Tags: discussion

It can't just be me noticing all these long-winded questions (and answers) about inflation in the SE. Is there some sort of funni jøk being played on us? Or more seriously, is there some sort of multi-accounting going on?

Comment: Probably expectations about getting answers on the matter became inflated and fed an inflationary loop on the questions.

Comment: I know me and you are just some ordinary goofballs, but our community can't have this little answering credibility can it?

Comment: Sorry, you just moved out of my English comfort zone! I don't understand your comment, plain English though it may be.

Comment: Could be related to FED interest rate decisions and surrounding discussion?

Comment: The Federal Reserve commits to an inflation level and must do so credibly. We have to commit to giving good answers and do so credibly. That was the gist of my joke, but the wording was not the best.